# Average magnetic field inside a sphere

Tags: magnetic-fields, magnetostatics

Griffiths, *Introduction to Electrodynamics*, prob. 5.59:

> Prove that the average magnetic field over a sphere of radius R, due to steady currents inside the sphere, is
> $$ {\bf B}_{\rm ave} = {\mu_0 \over 4\pi} {2 \ \! {\bf m} \over R^3}  $$
> where ${\bf m}$ is the total magnetic dipole moment of the sphere.

This is the magnetic counterpart of [this problem](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/589603/griffiths-on-averaging-and-the-macroscopic-electric-field). My doubts arise right at the beginning. I'll use the symbol $ \overset {?}{=} $ to mark the equalities I haven't understood.

[image]

The centre of the sphere coincides with the origin of my frame of reference.
$$
{\bf B}_{\rm ave} = {1 \over {4\over 3} \pi R^3} \int _{\tau} {\bf B}({\bf r}) \ \! d\tau =  \\
{1 \over {4\over 3} \pi R^3} \int _{\tau} {\bf \nabla \! \times \! A}({\bf r}) \space d\tau \overset {?}{=}
- {1 \over {4\over 3} \pi R^3} \oint _{\partial \tau} {\bf A}({\bf r})\! \times d{\bf a} = \\
- {1 \over {4\over 3} \pi R^3} \oint _{\partial \tau} \left[ {\mu_0 \over 4\pi} \int_{\tau}{{\bf J}({\bf r}')\over |{\bf r}-{\bf r}'| } d\tau ' \right] \! \times \! d{\bf a} \overset {?}{=}
- {3 \mu_0 \over (4\pi)^2 R^3}\int _{\tau}  {\bf J}({\bf r}') \! \times \! \left[\oint_{\partial \tau}{1\over |{\bf r}-{\bf r}'|} d{\bf a} \right] d\tau '
$$

The first $\overset{?}{=}$ seems to be Stokes' theorem, but sort of a generalized one. Is there a proof?

For the second $\overset {?}{=}$, the only explanation he gives is

> Note that $\bf J$ depends on the source point $\bf r'$, not on the field point $\bf r$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)[image]

2. Just flipping the double integral and triple integral basically, the mod term is a scalar and so can be moved so long as it is still integrated over area